# pouring mey chatat on a tattoo

Tags: clothing, parah-adumah, tattoo, maseches-parah

The Mishnah in [Parah 8:2](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Parah.8.2?lang=bi) teaches that if the mey chatat (parah adumah water) gets poured on someone's shoes or clothes, that water is not fit to be used for the parah adumah anymore. However, if it gets poured onto one's skin, it is fit to be used. My question is what if someone has a tattoo and the parah adumah water gets poured on that. Is that considered skin or clothing?

Comment: Why would it be considered clothing? Please edit to clarify

Comment: @DoubleAA Clothing in a sense that it could be mekabel tumah

Comment: And why might it be considered that? It's very clearly skin and not cloth.

Comment: How about a sun tan? Is that something you still consider regular skin?

Comment: Perhaps consider the tattoo ink like a grease stain fo a chatzitza. On the other hand perhaps it is like ink on a sofer or colors for a dyer. You should expand the question and ask in more detail.

Comment: @sabbahillel It's clearly like neither since it's not on the skin but under it.

Comment: Maybe since it's assur to be there in the first place, that's enough to mess it up? Are there any Mishnayos that talk about the Mei Chatas coming into contact with a general issur?

Comment: @PloniAlmoni Why would it be mekabel tumah independent of being skin? It's not the fact that it's clothing that makes it mekabel tumah - after all, people are as well. Something is mekabel tumah if it comes from the ground and has a functional use.